# Lotus Notes 7 - Cannot delete private folder

Tags: directory, lotus-notes, delete-directory

My `.nsf` has a private folder ( created by other person ) and I deleted it - right-click "Delete"( I have **Manager** access ).
It still appears in the **Folders** section, but when I **double-click** it, I get the message: **" Document deleted "** .

So, if it was deleted why it still shows in the **Folder** section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go into Domino Designer and see if the folder is still listed there.  I'm not sure if I'm describing it accurately, but Private folders essentially have an original, and then one copy per user, and perhaps you only deleted the copy.

If there's no sign of the folder, then I would try closing the database and then compact your workspace to get rid of any cached database information.

Comment: Open in designer and compact workspace are good hints... But the other thing is only true for "spofu"- folders (shared, private on first use) and not for any private folder...